# How to change a File's last Access/Modify/Change Date?

Tags: linux, file, hpc

I have some files on a scratch drive of a HPC server. The server automatically deletes files which are 2 weeks old.

Using `stat filename.txt` I can see the follow information. Is there a way to somehow open/touch/manipulate files to update the `Access` date to prevent deletion without actually changing the file?

```
File: ‘name’
Size: 2583438768    Blocks: 4819945    IO Block: 524288 regular file
Device: xxh/xxxd    Inode: 10354xxxx  Links: 1
Access: (/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (/)   Gid: (/)
Context: system_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0
Access: 2022-11-22 09:47:33.000000000 -0800
Modify: 2019-12-06 06:50:33.000000000 -0800
Change: 2022-11-22 16:54:55.000000000 -0800
Birth: -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Linux touch command](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/touch-command-in-linux-with-examples/), eg:

```
$ touch filename.txt
```